# Extract fetaure from GeoJSON layer and submit it to turf.js function in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, features, turf

A Leaflet layer holds some objects and each one has a bindpopup enabled,
now I can't pass a single of these objects to a turf function (in that case, buffer). I know I have to translate this single object into a GeoJSON layer, to make it readable, but I'm not successful.

"feature" with console.log, included in the code, reacts well in the following screenshot: it holds the single object that I need

[image]

but I'm unsuccessful with the rest :

> Uncaught TypeError: datatoconv.addTo is not a function

This is Leaflet.js, with Turf.js
and maybe this code: https://mappingforyou.eu/javascript/toGeoJSON.js

```
   var polygonObjects;
polygonObjects = L.geoJson(null, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        let btnBuffermodal = document.createElement('button');
        btnBuffermodal.className = 'ti-pencil';
        btnBuffermodal.innerHTML = '<b>Create perimeter...</b>';
        btnBuffermodal.onclick = function(targetmodal, context, geometry) {
            console.log(feature);
            var a = prompt("How many kilometers?", "10");
            if (a != null) {
                var bufferedLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
                    style: {
                        color: "black",
                        weight: 4,
                        fillColor: "white",
                        fillOpacity: 0
                    }
                }).addTo(map);
                var xdiv = a / 1;
                var datatoconv = feature.geometry;

                var templayer = new L.GeoJSON();
                templayer.addLayer(layer);
                //      console.log(templayer);
                templayer.addTo(map);
                var data = datatoconv.toGeoJSON();
                console.log(data);
                var buffered = turf.buffer(templayer, xdiv, {
                    units: 'kilometers'
                });
                console.log(buffered);

                _buildDigitiseModalBox('modalform', 'POLYGON', objectGeometry);
            }
        };

        let btnDiv = document.createElement('div')
        btnDiv.append(btnBuffermodal);

        layer.bindPopup(btnDiv);
    }
});
```

It's an analog code to this one:
https://github.com/andyprasetya/leaflet-CRUD/blob/master/app/create.js

Comment: Please edit your question ans explain a bit more about "I can't pass a single of these objects to a turf function". What exactly "can't pass" mean? Nothing happens? Wrong things happen? Errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: @TomazicM Hello; I've edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feature` parameter of `onEachFeature` option processing function is already pure plain GeoJSON object that is needed for `turf.buffer` method. As such it has no `.toGeoJSON()` method. You could apply this method to `layer` parameter which is actually Leaflet object, but you would get back exactly the same GeoJSON as in `feature` parameter.

So relevant part of your code is simply:

```
var buffered = turf.buffer(feature, xdiv, {
  units: 'kilometers'
});
```